# Closed VSCode, & Relaunched it, now dotnet build won't recognize the project

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, .net-7.0, relaunch

I have a file I downloaded to compile w/ dotnet (7.0), and it was taking the input. However, I restarted my computer, went through the same steps, and now when I try to run "dotnet build", I'm met with

Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in /Users/[USER]/Desktop/[PROJECT NAME], or pass the path to the project using --project.